# What happens when 2 Blade Barriers intersect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

I cast [Blade Barrier](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/bladeBarrier.html) in a wall in front of me. I then cast another Blade Barrier in a circle shape, so that part of the line intersects with part of the circle.

What happens at these points of intersection? Realistically I would assume 2 walls of blades to tear each other apart, but Pathfinder is mechanical, not realistic. Would a mob passing through this point of intersection take damage from both Barriers, or only one?

Comment: [For *3.5e* but rules remain unchanged.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8885/8610)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would apply the no-stacking rule from the [magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic) for this case :

> ### Stacking Effects
>
> **Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths**
>
> In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same
>   area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one
>   with the highest strength applies.

Then your Blade Barriers don't add up on the tiles where they intersect . Treat them as if only one Blade Barrier was there.

Comment: Guess I'll have to layer them next to each other, instead of stacking them ontop of each other